# Bug in OS X with JFileChooser UI (?)

Tags: java, user-interface, save, jfilechooser

I have, as many others, encountered and seen this question posted on this forum endless times; unfortunately never answered generally nor completely correctly.
When having a `JFileChooser` the UI irregularly shows up sometimes. This covers both when `Opening` and `Saving` a file.

For instance, if I have this code:
I try to read a .txt and put every line in an `Array` (allaNamn).

```
public static void getFile() {
    try {
        System.out.println("1");
        String aktuellMapp = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(aktuellMapp);
        System.out.println("2");
        int resultat = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
        System.out.println("3");
        if (resultat != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No file choosen.");
            NamnProgram.main(null);
        }

        String fil = fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();

        BufferedReader inFil = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fil));                 
        String rad = inFil.readLine();

        int counter = 0;
        while (rad != null) {
            rad = inFil.readLine();
            counter++;
        }
        if (counter == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Textfil is empty");
        }
        BufferedReader skrivFil = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fil));
        allaNamn = new String[counter]; 
        int antal = 0;        
        String sparaRad = skrivFil.readLine();
        while (antal < counter) {
            allaNamn[antal] = sparaRad;
            sparaRad = skrivFil.readLine();
            antal++;
        }       
        //Closing
        inFil.close();      
        skrivFil.close();       
    }
    catch (IOException e1) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Det misslyckades");
    }

}
```

I have tried debugging this, as well as a few other programmers; unfortunately without any success. I have a few `System.out.println()` in the method which print:

```
1
2
```

> "3" Does not show up, thus the problem is most likely in the:
>
> `int resultat = fc.showOpenDialog(null);`

Worth noting is that the program does not shut down, but keeps running without anything showing up -- no errors or such. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: fc.showOpenDialog() is modal and will block for input. Do you not get a dialog window ?

Comment: @Leet-Falcon What do you mean? Yes, I do not get a dialog window.

Answer (score 0):

`ShowOpenDialog()` stops the execution thread and waits for user input.
One options is that ShowOpenDialog() is not being executed on the AWT event dispatching thread.
(use the debugger to confirm)

If that is indeed your case - you could try calling:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
         getFile();
     }
 });
```

or even better than simply using [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-), use [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) API.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(this);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    try {
         File f = fc.getSelectedFile();
         gestorfile = new GestorFile(cadena, f.getCanonicalPath());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
         System.out.println("ERROR i/o");
          }
    }
```